# TextInputLayout having prefix and AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-studio, autocompletetextview, prefix, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout that contains an AutoCompleteTextView. The idea is that when the user starts typing the mobile number, some automatic suggestions should come. Since it is specifically for phone numbers, a fixed prefix "+91" is required.

`app:prefixText="+91"` is used for this purpose. It does show the prefix but it gets mixed with the hint and doesn't come properly (as it comes when EditText is used instead of AutoCompleteTextView). Checkout the images to see expected vs actual look.

[image: Actual-NOK-Prefix +91 Mixed with Hint]
[image: Expected-OK-Prefix +91 in correct position]

XML Layout file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".AddMob">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInpLayoutMob"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:hint="Mobile No."
                app:counterMaxLength="10"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:helperTextTextColor="@color/purple_700"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInpLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:prefixText="+91"
                app:prefixTextColor="@color/purple_700">
    
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewMob"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For `AutoCompleteTextView`s, you need to use the `ExposedDropdownMenu` version for the `TextInputLayout`'s `style`. That is, `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"`.